# Navigation in wpf not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, navigation

This is how i created Menu in WPF xaml-

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Width="auto"  TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"   Foreground="Black"  >
    <MenuItem Header="_Sale"></MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Header="_Invoice" x:Name="Invoice" Click="Invoice_Click" ></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Purchase"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header=" Inventory"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Settings"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

And click event for Invoice Tab of this menu-

```
public void Invoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         this.NavigationService.GetNavigationService(new Invoice());

        }
```

I want to get Invoice.xaml page that i have already created in same window but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried it through tutorials and all but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Change you button click event code as follow

```
    public void Invoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
     NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri("Invoice.xaml", UriKind.Relative));        
    }
```

Comment: It is showing error in line, It is asking for object reference.

Answer (score 0):

`this.NavigationService.GetNavigationService(new Invoice())` returns the `NavigationService` of the newly instantiated `Invoice` object (and here you are not assigning it to anything). What you want to do is call the `Navigate()` method on the `NavigationService` of `this`:

```
public void Invoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Invoice());
}
```

Comment: @Vanlalhrita, It is asking for assembly reference even after i added all required references. What should i do with it now?

Comment: Make sure your `Invoice` class is in scope. You can do this by either assuring it is in the same namespace, or including its namespace using a `using`.